# Python import no module found, but add "." works

Tags: python

My folder struct:

```
/root/main.py
/root/subdir/__init__.py
/root/subdir/b.py 
/root/subdir/c.py
```

/root/subdir/c.py:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

/root/subdir/b.py:

```
from c import foo
def func():
    pass
```

/root/main.py:

```
from subdir.b import func
```

python main will cause error:

```
No module named "c"
```

if I change /root/subdir/b.py to:

```
from .c import foo
def func():
    pass
```

it works properly.

Any one can explain the reason to cause the error?

Comment: Do you know what a *relative import* is in Python?

Comment: When you add the `.`. You are saying that you are getting the file from the current directory. Also adding to @KarlKnechtel answer. Consider reading this: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: Can you clarify what part of the error you do not understand? The reason is very literally that there is "No module named ``c``". There is only a module named ``subdir.c`` – just like you imported the module ``subdir.b`` instead of just ``b``.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm not very clearly. So should I add "." before imported file in subdir?